# Why did Elisha keep Geichazi as an assistant?

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, parashat-metzora, elisha

Although Geichazi seemingly has no share in Olam Haba [(Sanhedrin 105a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.105a.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), he was a long-standing servant of the Navi Elisha. Since Elisha likely knew Geichazi's character flaws, why would the Navi keep him as an assistant? (I am confused of how to understand Geichazi in general, how someone can serve such a holy individual yet still lose their Olam Haba)

Comment: In the Chassidisher stories, Gechazi is still Elisha's *shames*. Thus indicating an understanding that he has no autonomous *olam habah* only.

Comment: At the end of Kings 2:5 it doesn't seem like Elisha kept him as an assistant anymore. Not sure I understand the question here. Why did he wait so long to be rid of him?

Comment: I guess they had staffing shortages back then too.

Comment: The gemoro in sora says he wanted to become rich from Naamon. When it comes to money however holy one is, it doesnt help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that he kept him for so long, hoping that he would be able "to keep him in tow" and influence him to become better. Only once he created a Chillul HaShem by accepting Naamon's presents, could he no longer take the responsibility of having him around. And even then, Chazal (Sotah 47a) say that Elisha was punished for pushing him away too forcibly.